# Retrieving contacts from yahoo in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, yahoo-api

I am trying to build an application, which will enable to login to your yahoo account and retrieve your contacts.

I have registered my application [here](http://developer.apps.yahoo.com) to use the api.

I am using a [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html) oauth php library . Here I have to set the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret, which are the identifiers of the application, but how can I access a specific account on yahoo.

```
$client->CallAPI(
                    'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql', 
                    'GET', array(
                        'q'=>'select * from social.contacts where guid=me',
                        'format'=>'json'
                    ), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
```

The code that sends the request. I need some guidance.

Comment: The Yahoo site has some documentation and examples for using PHP with YQL: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#sdk_yql. In particular read the "Querying Private Data" section.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve contacts we need to generate acces token and signature key.Make a quick look on 
http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html and
http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-make-request.html